# Avoid Drag And Dop in Content Navigator

Tags: plugins, ibm-content-navigator

I want to develop a plugin to disable file drag and drop in IBM Content Navigator.

Currently i overwrite the following event:

```
  require(["dojo/_base/declare",
         "dojo/_base/lang","dojo/aspect"], 
function(declare, lang, aspect) {       
    aspect.around(Tree.prototype, "onExternalDrop", function (original) {
        return function (evt) {
            return;
        };
    });
});
```

What is wrong here, ICN alterts an error after loading the plugin: CIWEB2039

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you see any error when you deployed plugin? or when plug-in is getting loaded?

Comment: I get the following error during deployment: An error occured when evaluationg the JavaScript for the plugin xxxxxxxx.

Comment: Is that your plugin js file? are you using fireofx with firebug to see the error? It should provide you the js file name. May be that would help to investigate the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
"ecm/widget/listView/gridModules/DndFromDesktopAddDoc"
```

to require, and `DndFromDesktopAddDoc` to your function parameters.